# Guess the Number(Python)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

I know this is kind of stuff is somewhat done to death but please still try to review it fairly.

My code will only go within the interval of [1,9]

```py
def guessing_game():
    no_of_guess = 0
    c = "y"
    import random
    a = random.randint(1,9)
    while c == "y":
        b = input("Enter a guess: ")
        if b.isdigit():
            if int(b) == a:
                c = input("You got it! Play again? Enter \"Y\" if yes, and anything else to exit. ").lower()
                no_of_guess +=1
                a = random.randint(1,9)
            elif int(b) > a:
                c = input("Too high. Try again? Enter \"Y\" if yes, and anything else to exit. ").lower()
                no_of_guess +=1
            else:
                c = input("Too small. Try again? Enter \"Y\" if yes, and anything else to exit. ").lower()
                no_of_guess +=1 
        else:
            c = input("Haha. Try again? Enter \"Y\" if yes, and anything else to exit. ").lower()
    if c != "y":
        print("How unfortunate. Well, you made %s guess(es)."%no_of_guess)


guessing_game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few minor things:

- Imports should generally be at the module level, not inside functions.
- Use more intention-revealing variable names. `no_of_guess` is borderline OK, but `a`, `b` and `c` don't tell me anything.
- Think about control flow more carefully. For example:

  - you increment the guess counter for any numerical input, so you don't necessarily need to wait for the conditional checks; and
  - outside the loop do you really need to recheck whether the input wasn't `"y"`?
- You can use single-quoted strings to avoid escaping double quote within them.
- You can also reduce duplication by extracting functions and constants

With these suggestions addressed:

```
import random

RULES = 'Enter "Y" if yes, and anything else to exit. '

def win_prompt():
    return input("You got it! Play again? " + RULES).lower()

def lose_prompt(message):
    return input(message + " Try again? " + RULES).lower()

def guessing_game():
    number_of_guesses = 0
    target = random.randint(1,9)
    continuing = "y"
    while continuing == "y":
        guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
        if guess.isdigit():
            number_of_guesses += 1
            if int(guess) == target:
                continuing = win_prompt()               
                target = random.randint(1,9)
            elif int(guess) > target:
                continuing = lose_prompt("Too high.")
            else:
                continuing = lose_prompt("Too small.") 
        else:
            continuing = lose_prompt("Haha.")
    print("How unfortunate. Well, you made %s guess(es)." % number_of_guesses)


guessing_game()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This helps a lot, especially the technique with the lose_prompt functions. I used a,b,c because I got lazy lol, but yeah I'll try to be more specific next time. Also that was a big brain fart with the c!='y' check, haha. Thanks again.